# How to Print out the maximum speed of the agent as the output consistently shows zero

Tags: output, anylogic, agent

I am encountering difficulties setting the maximum speed for my agents and unable to obtain the correct value when attempting to print it. The output consistently shows zero. I would appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue.

**Input code and Output display**
[image: Input code and Output display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per code-complete, `getSpeed` returns the assigned speed of the agent, not the actual current speed it moves at, this may be zero when it is stationary:
[image]

Call your traceln while the agent moves and you get the speed.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin . With the free space model I tried to call in transport fleet and move by transport but still the values is zero.  Could you please suggest me  where should I call ?

Comment: Best open a new issue and share the details of your setup, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow